# Extracting specific words from a string query [javaScript]

Tags: javascript

I have a string query

```
const query = '(travel OR explore OR vacation OR trip) NOT (app OR agency) AND flight';
```

I want to store the words inside "NOT" block in an array.
What could be the most effective approach for this?

Expected result - ["app", "agency"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const query = '(travel OR explore OR vacation OR trip) NOT (app OR agency) AND flight';
function useRegex(input) {
    let regex = /\(([a-zA-Z]+( [a-zA-Z]+)+)\) NOT \(([a-zA-Z]+( [a-zA-Z]+)+)\) ([A-Za-z0-9]+( [A-Za-z0-9]+)+)/i;
    return input.match(regex);
}
console.log(useRegex(query)[3]);
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `match()`, *twice*:

```js
const query = '(travel OR explore OR vacation OR trip) NOT (app OR agency) AND flight';
var terms = query.match(/\bNOT\s*\((.*?)\)/)[1]
                 .match(/\w+/g)
                 .filter(x => x !== "OR" && x !== "AND");
console.log(terms);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1**: Split the query before and after `NOT` keyword using `query.split('NOT')`

-> Here only data after `NOT` is needed so we can use, `query.split('NOT')[1]`

**Step 2**: Use regex `rx.exec(res)[1]` to get the value in between the paranthesis.

**Step 3**: Get the values before and after `OR`.

```js
const query = '(travel OR explore OR vacation OR trip) NOT (app OR agency) AND flight';

const res = query.split('NOT')[1]; 
const rx = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
const result = rx.exec(res)[1].split(' OR ');


console.log(result);
```